# É possível obter o texto da requisição HTTP?

Tags: php, http

As requisições HTTP/HTTPS são enviadas como texto tendo o formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na ordem:

1. A linha inicial com o método HTTP e a versão
2. Os cabeçalhos no formato `chave: valor`
3. Uma linha em branco
4. O corpo da requisição

É possível obter a string completa dessa requisição? Ela fica salva em algum arquivo `.txt` no diretório `/tmp`?

Comment: Seria importante contextualizar o problema que você está tentando resolver. Possível é, porque milhares de ferramentas implementam isso, agora qual a sua necessidade nesse caso específico?

Comment: @JulianoNunes não tem um contexto específico é mais uma curiosidade do que um problema

Comment: Então, vamos lá. A requisição em si não fica salva em arquivo de texto, o que ocorre é que você consegue via algum sniffer de rede ou até mesmo através do seu navegador visualizar o tráfego da sua máquina e pegar essa informações. Fazendo a requisição via postman também é possível. Se você estiver em um servidor web por exemplo, é possível rastrear todas as requisições que estão sendo feitas. Enfim, existem diversas formas de fazer, mas como sua pergunta está muito aberta fica difícil saber qual direção te apontar.

Comment: @JulianoNunes não tenho certeza se entendeu, a ideia é que meu backend em PHP consiga recuperar essa string, não o navegador ou softwares de terceiros (exceto libs/frameworks PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue recuperar todas essas informações no PHP. Elas não ficam disponíveis em um arquivo como foi dito pelo "por favor excluir minha conta". Na imagem, você tem uma requisição via POST, os cabeçalhos e no corpo todas as informações enviadas.

**Na requisição...**

Para recuperar o tipo de requisição junto com os cabeçalhos você pode fazer isso:

```
$string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\n"; // pega o tipo de requisição

# pega e armazena todos os cabeçalhos
foreach(getallheaders() as $nome => $valor)
$string .= $nome." : ".$valor."\n";
```

Irá ficar algo parecido com o que está na sua imagem.

Para pegar o corpo você pode usar o `$_REQUEST` para pegar tudo($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE) que foi enviado.
Ficaria assim:

```
$string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\n";
foreach(getallheaders() as $nome => $valor)
    $string .= $nome." : ".$valor."\n";

$string .= "Body:\n";
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
    $string .= $key." : ".$value."\n";
```

**Na resposta...**

Na resposta, você pode urilizar o `http_response_code()`, que quando não é informado no parâmetro com o tipo de resposta, ele retorna a resposta atual do servidor.

E para pegar todos os cabeçalhos enviados pelo servidor, você pode usar o [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) que inclusive envia o status da resposta.

O corpo da resposta é com você... Pode ser um html, xml, um "olá mundo!" qualquer coisa exibida, ou nada. E você pode recuperar de várias formas como com o  `file_get_contents()` caso esta resposta tenha um status 200, ou seja, caso não haja erros.