# Pular a rota devido a parametro mal formatado é um erro de sintaxe?

Tags: http, url, rotas

Por exemplo, eu tenho a rota `GET: /user/{id}`, sendo que o id passa por uma validação de expressão regular do tipo `[0-9]+`. Ao realizar requisições com o verbo GET para as seguintes URLs:

- `/user/17`, retorna os dados do usuário de id igual a 17
- `/user/null`, retorna o status 404, como se não existisse a rota

Isso seria um erro de sintaxe? Deveria ser retornado um 400?

E no caso de em vez de um parâmetro na URL inválido, um parâmetro no corpo, por exemplo, uma rota que precisa de dois parâmetros, `oldPassword` e `newPassword`, mas a requisição só tem `newPassword`?

Comment: Se a requisição está errada/incompleta, 400. A "Bad Request" é justamente responder um "olha, o erro foi aí do seu lado, não no servidor. Se vira para corrigir".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então ambos os casos que citei estariam incorretos retornar 404?

Comment: No meu entendimento, sim. A rota existe e foi encontrada, não faz sentido responder com 404.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A URL é um valor opaco por definição, o que significa que ela não necessariamente reflete a estrutura da sua aplicação; tanto que acessar `/user/1` não é, necessariamente, acessar o arquivo em `/user/1/index.html`, a URL pode não representar a organização de pastas (ou pode, como é comum para os arquivos estáticos).

Dito isso, a resposta final à sua pergunta é: depende dos requisitos da sua aplicação.

Não podemos dizer o que é certo ou errado, pois em uma aplicação pode fazer sentido e em outras não. Sendo a URL opaca, em diferentes aplicações ela pode representar diferentes recursos e, assim, exigir diferentes respostas.

Vamos começar com o contra-argumento da sua pergunta: temos uma aplicação em que eu posso acessar as informações de um usuário tanto com `/user/1` quanto `/user/anderson-carlos-woss`. Acontece que no primeiro caso eu informei o ID do usuário, enquanto no segundo eu informei o nome. Na minha aplicação eu garanto que ambos serão únicos para cada usuário. Ou seja, acessar o recurso `/user/null`, por exemplo, faria com que minha aplicação chegasse ao recurso correto (usuários), provavelmente existiria uma condição que verificaria se o valor é um número; se for, busca pelo id, caso contrário busca pelo nome. Neste caso, seria buscado do banco o usuário com nome Null e se não encontrado geraria uma resposta de erro.

Percebe que neste caso o recurso da aplicação foi identificado corretamente, foi feito toda a busca e não encontrou o registro no banco? Para esta situação a resposta indicada seria a 404 Not Found, pois sua aplicação conseguiu processar a requisição com sucesso, somente não encontrou o recurso que o cliente requisitou.

Na sua pergunta você cita:

> ... sendo que o id passa por uma validação de expressão regular do tipo `[0-9]+`

E é isso que define qual utilizar. Os requisitos da sua aplicação demandam que o id informado pela URL **deve ser** um valor inteiro não negativo. Se o cliente solicitar o recurso `/user/null`, é mais interessante você informá-lo que a requisição está errada e que ele precisa corrigi-la antes de tentar novamente. Veja, é um problema **na requisição**, não na aplicação. Erros na requisição são informados com a resposta 400 Bad Request, que basicamente diz ao cliente "cara, sua requisição não faz sentido, não sei o que fazer com ela".

Resumindo:

- Responda com 404 Not Found quando existir a rota naquele formato, mas o recurso em questão não foi encontrado;
- Responda com 400 Bad Request quando não existir a rota naquele formato;

Então é errado eu enviar a resposta 404 neste caso? Não! Depende da sua aplicação. Algumas aplicações optam por enviar a resposta 404 mesmo que a requisição esteja errada para ocultar a estrutura da própria aplicação. Digamos que um usuário com más intenções tente invadir o recurso `/user/null` e recebe a resposta 400 ele saberá que a requisição está errada e tentará fazer o ataque em um recurso semelhante, até obter outra resposta; enquanto se ele receber a resposta 404 ele poderá achar que o recurso não existe e desistir do ataque. Depende de que recurso estamos tratando, de qual contexto ele será usado e de quais são os requisitos da aplicação.

A minha visão é bem simples: a aplicação deve estar protegida contra ataques em qualquer recurso, não é uma resposta HTTP que mudará isso, então eu busco sempre utilizar aquela que facilita para o cliente (bem intencionado).

> E no caso de em vez de um parâmetro na URL inválido, um parâmetro no corpo, por exemplo, uma rota que precisa de dois parâmetros, `oldPassword` e `newPassword`, mas a requisição só tem `newPassword`?

Mesma situação. Sua aplicação saberá o que fazer quando só tiver um dos valores? Se sim, a requisição é válida. Se não, a aplicação não tem o que fazer com a requisição, então responda com 400 Bad Request.

Lembre-se que não é feio dizer pro cliente que ele está errado. Se ele fez uma requisição errada, avise-o para que ele possa corrigir.

---

Outra forma de analisar o problema é verificando as definições de cada resposta:

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> *The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.*

Traduzindo, a requisição pode não ter sida entendida pelo servidor devido à sintaxe mal formatada. O cliente NÃO DEVE repetir a requisição sem modificações.

Isto é, se eu acessar hoje o recurso `/user/null` e obter a resposta 400, saberei que **sempre** que eu fizer essa mesma requisição eu terei a mesma resposta. Se existe a possibilidade de amanhã (ou outro momento) o recurso existir, então a resposta deverá ser 404, não 400. Ah, mas e se um dia eu quiser criar esse recurso, então já devo usar a resposta 404? Não. Você responde conforme sua aplicação é hoje. No dia que você for criar o novo recurso você altera a resposta.

> **404 Not Found**
>
> *The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.*

Traduzindo, o servidor não encontrou resultados para a URI requisitada. Nenhuma indicação é dada sobre se a condição é temporária ou permanente. A resposta 410 (Gone) deve ser utilizada se o servidor sabe, de alguma maneira, que o recurso existiu e foi permanentemente removido sem nenhum endereço alternativo. Esta resposta é comumente utilizada quando o servidor não deseja revelar o motivo real da requisição ser recusada.

Neste caso, responder com 404 quando acessar `/user/null` não significa que um dia esse recurso existirá. Indica apenas que hoje não existe e que há a possibilidade de existir um dia. Se o recurso existiu e foi excluído, a aplicação pode responder com 410 (isso é comum em aplicações que efetuam o *soft-delete*).

Também como comentado anteriormente, a resposta 404 é mais genérica e pode ser utilizada em ocasiões diversas, seja para não revelar informações da aplicação, seja porque não havia respostas melhores para a situação.

---

Outra dúvida que é bastante comum é como diferenciar se a rota não existe ou se o registro não existe ao receber a resposta 404. Se eu acesso `/user/1` e recebo a resposta 404 significa que eu deveria tentar outra rota, como `/usuario/1`, ou minha rota está certa e é id 1 que não existe no banco?

Para fazer essa diferenciação é comum utilizar o corpo da resposta enviando uma mensagem com detalhes sobre o motivo dela ter sido gerada.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"error": "Rota não encontrada"}
```

Ou

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"error": "Usuário 1 não encontrado"}
```

Você pode, inclusive, alterar a descrição da resposta (*response reason*) livremente, porém não é tão depender dela para indicar o erro, pois é muito mais fácil trabalhar com o corpo da resposta que sua descrição. Se o cliente for algo mais visual ao usuário, como o Postman, talvez seja interessante utilizá-la:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 User Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"error": "Usuário 1 não encontrado"}
```

Isso pode facilitar para o usuário, pois não demanda dele analisar um possível JSON no corpo da resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Respondeu 250% a pergunta :)

Comment: @woss, no caso de enviar apenas `newPassword` e não `oldPassword`, não seria um 422 Unprocessable Entity?

Answer (score 1):

Não, esse comportamento está correto, essa rota que você informou não existe, eu fiz um script rápido em JS para exemplificar isso, onde eu testo a expressão regular que você está utilizando para validar a rota:

```js
paths_test = ["/user/17", "/user/null"]

paths_test.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x.match('[0-9]+') || `Rota não encontrada: ${x}`);
})
```

O path parameter `null` não da match com a sua rota `/user/{id}`, ele vai retornar 404 pois não encontrou nenhuma rota que atenda a requisição `/user/null` já que a única existente valida se o parâmetro é numérico através de uma expressão regular.

Sobre a segunda pergunta é a relacionado a primeira certo? Então acho que a mesma lógica se aplica.

Comment: Sua resposta me parece confusa, não diz se tá ou não certo, parece que está dizendo "tanto faz"

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: Pelo que pude entender, você só testou pela existência de dígitos na string. Creio que uma validação melhor fosse `x.match('/[0-9]+$')`, onde garanto que os números devem existir após a barra. Mesmo assim, não ficou muito óbvio na minha leiga cabeça a relação entre esse `match` e a questão...

Answer (score 0):

O **erro 404** é um código de resposta HTTP que indica que o cliente pôde comunicar com o servidor, mas o servidor não pôde encontrar o que foi pedido. No seu caso foi possível comunicar com o servidor mas não foi possível encontrar o que você procura que é uma URL específica (página específica) , ou seja, o retorno 404 é correto porque ele não encontra sua rota (página não encontrada).

O comportamento está correto mas a lógica errada. Um identificador não pode ser nulo, logo, você já deveria trazer somente ID'S válidos para montar sua URL, pois o ID é um parâmetro para se montar a sua rota (no máximo validar que o id não seja nulo como também não pode ser diferente de numérico). Ou seja não faz sentido em montar a URL da página de um usuário que não existe. Se você cria um tabela no banco de dados e efetua um insert o campo ID como chave primária assume o valor 1 e não 0 ou NULL.
Há contextos em que queremos buscar valores em que podem vir campos nulos, mas não é o seu. Se é um parâmetro obrigatório para formar uma instrução e ele vem de uma consulta, de um array, ou um campo informado, não pode vir nulo.

Comment: E se a URL fosse montada por um atacante? Não seria ele, então, quem montou a URL, porém ela seria gramaticalmente válida no que tange URLs

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário. O que significa"montada por um atacante"? Estou chamando a atenção para "se não existe o id do usuário não é possível montar a url". Logo ele já tem que trazer todos os id's válidos para que todas as rotas sejam montadas sem falha.

Comment: Nesse trecho "você já deveria trazer somente ID'S válidos para montar sua URL". Aqui está dizendo que quem irá montar a URL é o autor. Porém, isso normalmente não é verdade. Veja mais algumas perguntas interessantes do Guilherme, como [métodos HTTP na prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300329/64969), [retorno do `OPTIONS`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/339104/64969), [método `DELETE` possuir corpo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301436/64969) e [obter a comunicação textual de uma chamada HTTp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340047/64969). [1/3]

Comment: Em todas elas o Guilherme está indo além das requisições típicas de browser (`GET`/`POST`) para uma abordagem mais semântica, onde o método HTTP importa para que ele possa fazer um tratamento especial. Em especial, a [métodos HTTP na prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300329/64969) dorme na minha cabeceira todo dia para que eu possa fazer uma boa API no trabalho no dia seguinte. E, como os métodos fora do `GET` e do `POST` não são trivialmente acessíveis pelo browser, o cliente dele é uma aplicação. Logo, não faz nem sentido falar em "página". [2/3]

Comment: Como ele é acessado por uma aplicação, um usuário que pretende obter dados sigilosos pode tentar se passar pela aplicação em questão, fazendo a [requisição HTTP textualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340047/64969), por exemplo. [3/3]

Comment: Sobre rotas, por que ele deveria carregar todas elas? Normalmente isso gasta mais memória. Basta por alguém que identifique que, se for `/user/{id}` para um `{id}` arbitrário, retorne o resultado de uma computação passando esse `{id}` como argumento

Comment: Todas as respostas 4xx implicam que a comunicação com o servidor foi bem sucedida e que falhou devido ao erro por parte do cliente, tanto que são chamadas de "client errors". Não entendo como isso pode ser argumento para se dizer que o correto é a 404. Também não entendi quando você comenta sobre "montar a URL"; parece que está presumindo que será acessadas somente as URLs presentes na página e não será acessadas nenhuma manualmente ou geradas a partir de um script de invasão buscando falhas na aplicação. Você discordaria de alguma coisa da minha resposta?

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer. Ele tem o script que monta a URL tanto que ele valida se o campo ID é númerico. Caso ele não queira carregar todos os ID's válidos é só na parte do código que ele valida se é númerico acrescentar que não pode ser nulo também. Em relação a pessoa inserir um código malicioso é por isso que ele faz a validação de que seja númerico e para não apresentar  o erro 404, deve evitar que o id seja diferente de nulo (pois assim existirá rota). Informei na minha resposta também.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consideraria um **erro de sintaxe**: *400 - Bad Request*.

Se você está buscando por usuários com determinado número de identificador, o número `null` não é um número válido. Portanto, isto é considerado uma request "ruim" (*bad request*), ou seja, o cliente não observou a forma correta do parâmetro passado e ele deve fazer a correção necessária antes de tentar novamente.

O *404 - Not Found* não faz sentido aqui, pois o usuário de identificador `null` é um identificador inválido **antes** de ser considerado um usuário que não existe (o que de certa forma é também verdade).

> E no caso de em vez de um parâmetro na URL inválido, um parâmetro no corpo, por exemplo, uma rota que precisa de dois parâmetros, oldPassword e newPassword, mas a requisição só tem newPassword?

Excelente pergunta. Se as duas informações são obrigatórias, você pode retornar também um *400 - Bad Request*. Se eu não me engano, este é o comportamento padrão do framework Spring quando as informações do *body* da *request* são anotadas com `@NotNull` e o cliente não as preencheu.

No mais, também faria a seguinte alteração no seu endpoint: ao invés de usar `/user/` usar `/users/`.

Comment: Um motivo para se retornar 404 seria para tentar alguma forma de segurança por obscurantismo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, pode ser um motivo. Algumas soluções podem variar dependendo do contexto, tanto que estas discussões de qual o status HTTP correto em determinadas situações existem aos montes. O que apreendi ao final é que o mais importante em uma API é manter, independente da decisão tomada, o mesmo padrão.